# Allowing access to /uploads/ in WordPress if user = x

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

We currently have a WordPress site, which is going to be used as an online portal.

In this portal, we will create several logins, with a custom function to redirect a user to a page only they can access.

This means User A can ONLY access User-A page.

From here, we are going to be uploading documents for the user to download, meaning it will be private (As no other user can access it, and we use force login to make users login.)

Problem we have:
If we upload a file to 'User-A', it still goes to /wp-content/uploads/user-a.pdf/, meaning 'User-B' could find this file if they get the URL.

I've looked at several plugins to try find a solution, but still with no luck.

We need to be able to either:

- Stop access to the media folders by URL
- Only allow certain Users to access certain URLS.

any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: i suggest you start by looking at htacces

Comment: Can you expand on this?